# Where do I set flags like $OutDir in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am looking through project properties and am seeing variables like $OutDir for output directory. Where can I change this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of those can be set, and some cannot. For example, $OutDir would be set under Project Properties, Configuration Properties -> General -> Output directory for C++ projects, and Project Properties -> Build -> Output path for C# projects.

Many of them cannot be changed explicitly. For example, $(SolutionDir) is always the full path to the .sln file. You can move the file, but you cannot change the value explicitly.

For a C++ project, most text fields have a dropdown menu, which will let you bring up an edit window. Click on "Macros" to show them all, and their current values. For a C# project, I think the only place they can be used is in the build events tab: Click the button to bring up a separate edit window, and it will have the same "Macros" button.

Answer (score 3):

This stuff is documented by Microsoft in [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx). That link is for Visual Studio 2015, but I don't think much has changed.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for Phil. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change it for a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019 and needed some time to find the option.

Go to **Project Properties** -> **Configuration Properties** -> **General** -> **Output Directory** and **set the value for the $(OutDir)**, then click **Apply** -> **Ok**.

[image]